# How to print SQL Table without extra characters either side of values?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

my code;

```
items_orderedSQL = cursor.fetchall()
        print(f"\n{cust_name} ordered;\n{items_orderedSQL}")
```

I want to print a table, but its outputting this;

```
[('Bauble', 4), ('Tinsel', 3), ('Tree', 7)]
```

However I don' t want the extra characters, I want it to be user friendly but I am not sure how to going around this. Preferably I'd like it to output;

```
Bauble - 4
Tinsel - 3
Tree - 7
```

or something similar. Thank you. (sqlite3)

Comment: Write a loop that formats the tuples in whatever way you want. There's nothing built-in that will do that format for you.

Comment: `print(f"{cust_name} ordered;", *(f"{n} - {v}" for n, v in items_orderedSQL), sep="\n")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
items_orderedSQL = [('Bauble', 4), ('Tinsel', 3), ('Tree', 7)]

for item in items_orderedSQL:
    print(f"{item[0]} - {item[1]}")
```

`items_orderedSQL` is a list of tuples. The `for` loop walks through the list, and each of the two items in the tuple is accessed by index.

Comment: thank you! How did you get rid of the extra characters?

Comment: @iaivazovski You're welcome! I updated the answer with information about tuple element access. If you're satisfied kindly accept the answer by clicking on the check.